# Function to return stripped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, strip, removing-whitespace

I have a dataframe from CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'mike.csv'
main_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

I need a function that will strip all string columns' (there are also numeric columns) contents from whitespaces and then return such stripped dataframe. In the below function, the stripping seems to work fine, but I don't know how to return the stripped dataframe:

```
def strip_whitespace(dataframe):
    dataframe_strings = dataframe.select_dtypes(['object'])
    dataframe[dataframe_strings.columns] = dataframe_strings.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
    return # how to return a stripped dataframe here?
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'mike.csv'
main_df = pd.read_csv(filename)

def strip_whitespace(dataframe):
    dataframe_strings = dataframe.select_dtypes(['object'])
    dataframe[dataframe_strings.columns] = dataframe_strings.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
    return stripped_dataframe # ?

stripped_main_df = strip_whitespace(main_df) # should be stripped df
```

Comment: Do you think `return dataframe` ?

Comment: you can `return dataframe`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because the problem is a result of a typographical error (wrong variable name) plus bad indentation.

Comment: Also the question doesn't really have anything to do with pandas here, more like an issue with your understanding of functions and variables. I'd recommend hitting the books are reading some documentation beforehand.

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks for suggestions, but my problem is more complex and persists after using the variable name suggested. In fact, this is the variable name I used in the first place, but it didn't work, hence my question. I have also corrected the indentation.

Comment: Then you should be providing a [mcve] which makes it possible for us to reproduce your problem and offer a solution. Posting non-runnable code and saying "it doesn't work" is not helpful to you, me, or the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need parameter `skipinitialspace=True` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
main_df = pd.read_csv(filename, skipinitialspace=True)
```

And then stripping columns is not necessary.

---

But if need use your function:

```
return dataframe
```

Comment: Will `skipinitialspace=True` strip also trailing spaces?

Comment: @barciewicz - Yes, but it depends of data, because it skip spaces after delimiter.

Comment: @barciewicz - So basically I suggest use this parameter and if still problem use yur function.